# Call sidebar from a template

Tags: widgets, sidebar, theme-twenty-twelve

I need to call a sidebar into my header. I've switched to the new twenty twelve theme and created my own child theme. With this new theme I decided to keep things organised and together, so I put my widgets functions, stylesheet and two new sidebar templates (one for header and one for footer widgets) in one folder called `pgwidgets`.

This is the call i used in my header

```
<? if ( is_front_page() ) : ?>  
<?php get_sidebar( 'homepage' ) ; ?>
<?php endif ; ?>
```

This calls the `sidebar-homepage.php` file into my header from the themes' root directory. How do I change the `get_sidebar( 'homepage' )` part to call the sidebar from the pgwidgets folderfolder (`pgwidgets/sidebar-homepage.php`)

Comment: You should follow the structure of WP file structure http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files_List Going away from that is just making it more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible with `get_sidebar()`.

From that function’s body:

```
function get_sidebar( $name = null ) {
    do_action( 'get_sidebar', $name );

    $templates = array();
    if ( isset($name) )
        $templates[] = "sidebar-{$name}.php";

    $templates[] = 'sidebar.php';
```

So if you pass a `$name` or any other custom value to the function, they will be set between two fixed strings.

You can use `locate_template()` instead:

```
locate_template( 'pgwidgets/sidebar-homepage.php', TRUE );
```

Comment: toscho, excellent!!! many thanks for your help, works like a charm