# Is there some way to put a theme's header.php and footer.php in a subdir

Tags: templates, directory

and still call them with get_header() / get_footer()?

For example {themedir}/templates/headers/header.php
of {themedir}/templates/footers/footer.php

With templates this is easy, but I can't get it to work with get_header() and get_footer().

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: No, but see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96566/73) for an alternative.

Comment: Thanks mate! Unfortunately I can't upvote your comment yet (if that's at all possible) but now at least I know that I'll need to work around it.